# Copying files taking long time using jcifs

Tags: java, jcifs

I am copying the remote file from windows shared folder to linux machine. It is taking long time to copy. Out of 320 MB only 200 Kb copied in 10 hrs.

Here is my code snippet:

```
try {
    String user = "xxxx";
    String pass ="yyyy";    
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("",
            user, pass);
    String sharepath ="smb://aa.bb.com/root/Test/Access.mdb";           
    SmbFile remoteFile = new SmbFile (sharepath, auth);

    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("/home/test/Access.mdb");
    InputStream is = remoteFile.getInputStream();
    int ch;
    while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
        os.write(ch);
    }
    os.close();
    is.close();

} catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 

}
```

How can I reduce the time to copy?

Answer (score 1):

If it takes 10 *hours* to copy 200KB, then something is seriously wrong with your setup. There might be a network issue or your code and setup might trigger a bug in jcifs or Windows. Enable all the logging and maybe use a debugger and a profile to see where the time is spent.

As a quick workaround, you may consider using a different protocol like SSH or rsync with SSH.

Or have a look at a remote file system like [XtreemFS](http://www.xtreemfs.org/) (might be overkill in your case, though).

Answer (score 0):

**Streaming from/to most resources is faster when using buffering.**

Use `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream` for that purpose:

```
OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/home/test/Access.mdb"));
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(remoteFile.getInputStream());
```

Before closing an `OutputStream`, **always `flush()`**, this is crucial when any of the wrapped streams uses buffering. Closing without flushing will result in data loss.

```
os.flush();
os.close();
is.close();
```